# Null record added when loading view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm new to asp.net MVC. In below code i'm trying to add a record to the database. It works fine but it adds a null record to the database each time i load the view.

**Model:**

```
 public class multi
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }


        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }



 public class CategoryRepository
    {

private BusDataClassesDataContext dc = new BusDataClassesDataContext();

 public void Save()
        {
            dc.SubmitChanges();
        }

         public void AddMulti(multi mu)
                {
                    tblCategory cat = new tblCategory();
                    cat.CategoryName = mu.CategoryName;
                    cat.Description = mu.Description;

                    tblUser user = new tblUser();
                    user.DisplayName = mu.DisplayName;
                    user.Email = mu.Email;

                    dc.tblCategories.InsertOnSubmit(cat);
                    dc.tblUsers.InsertOnSubmit(user);
                }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
CategoryRepository cat = new CategoryRepository();

    public ActionResult AddMulti(multi mu)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    cat.AddMulti(mu);
                    cat.Save();
                    return View(mu);

                }
                else
                {
                    return View(mu);

                }
            }
```

**View:**

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>


            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CategoryName) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DisplayName) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayName) %>
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) %>
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you missing `[Required]` in your model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have no validation on your model, so `ModelState.IsValid` is always true. You then add a new Category via `AddMulti`. Because this controller method is the only one specified, it's used for both GET and POST requests. This means that, every time you load the page and render the form, you create a new record with the empty values in the model.

Try splitting your Controller out into `HttpPost` and `HttpGet` methods:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMulti(multi mu)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        cat.AddMulti(mu);
        cat.Save();
        return View(mu);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(mu);
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddMulti()
{
    return View();
}
```

Now, when you access the page via a GET request (i.e. when you first access it, before posting the form), the second action method is fired, so you won't create that new record.

You'll also probably want to add some validation attributes to your model. Because it looks like you're passing domain models directly to views, you should also look into creating separate [view models](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/04/13/asp-net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx).

Comment: Hello  i added HttpPost on my controller method.Now i'm getting "404 page not found error"

Comment: This is because you also need to create the `HttpGet` method I've shown above. Now that your previous method is POST only, there is nothing to handle GET requests unless you create a separate method.

Comment: where do i add this method? can not add the method with same parameter types on the same cotroller class

Comment: Hi - Try adding the method without the parameters (see my edit above) as you won't need them during the GET request anyway.

Comment: No problem - it's worth remembering, also, that it is conventional to have separate methods for GET and POST requests as they serve different purposes (the first to show your form, the second to handle submissions).